# Does it make sense for a view matrix to have a scale?

Tags: 2d, 3d, matrix

When building a view matrix from an SRT matrix multiply, examples ([here](https://www.3dgep.com/understanding-the-view-matrix/#The_View_Matrix) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/view-transform)) only ever compose it with a R and T. Does it make sense to have the S component be anything other than the identity? What does it mean to scale the view matrix anyway?